# jQuery and ASP.NET controls visibility in code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my codebehind, I set the display property of an asp.net control to none as follows;

```
fuDoc.Attributes("style") = "display:none;" 'fuDoc is a FileUpload control.
```

On my page, if the user wants to upload a document, they click on a link, which by using jQuery, I set the `display` property to `'block'` by using .show() as follows;

```
$('#fuDoc').show();
```

I also tried;

```
$('#fuDoc').attr('style', 'display:block;');
```

now, on form submit, I need to check if the `fuDoc` is `visible` and if so, do the standard file upload process e.g. check `.HasFile` etc..

However, although the fuDoc control is set to `display:block` in HTML with no problem, the following asp.net code always produces True

```
If fuDoc.Attributes("style") = "display:none;" Then 'always results to true
```

What is the reason for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: the FileUpload control is NOT created dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than relying on detecting whether or not the FileUpload is visible on the page, you could include a TextBox or HiddenField such as:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtIsFileUploadShown" runat="server" cssclass="txtisfileuploadshown" Text="0" style="display:none;" />
```

This control will be hidden on your page, storing the value of `0` by default.

Whenever you hide/show the file upload, change your code to also change this value:

```
$('#fuDoc').show();
$(".txtisfileuploadshown").val('1');
```

When hiding:

```
$('#fuDoc').hide();
$(".txtisfileuploadshown").val('0');
```

Then in your code-behind on post back, simply check:

```
If IsNumeric(txtisfileuploadshown.text) AndAlso Cint(txtisfileuploadshown.text)=1 Then
   'Do HasFile validation here.
End
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `style` attributes changes on the client are not persisted during a postback.

One possible fix would be use a hiddenfield to store the state of the `fuDoc` control.

Comment: thank you codrin, voted up for being first, but had to accept the other since it includes example and might be helpful for others having similar problems.